# ArrayList using the .add .size and .get methods cannot resolve methods why?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi everyone i'm new here and i'm not sure if this has been covered before but will be looking until i receive some answers or find them myself if i find them i will take this post down. Anyways my problem is i'm following along with this online course and in the video the example being taught is exactly as I've written down in the ide I've quadruple checked to make sure there are no differences but when the teacher goes to run the code it executes fine when I do it shows cannot resolve method errors where i'm trying to add names to an `ArrayList` with `names.add("James")` etc.. and when I try to use `name.size` in my for loop or `names.get` in my `println` command i'm really lost as to why this keeps happening and not sure how to go about fixing it. Again i'm new to this language and forum so if I've not given a clear enough explanation i apologize i will attach the code I've done to show you exactly what it is i'm dealing with. Thanks for any help!

```
package com.example.arrays;

import java.util.ArrayList

public class ArrayList
{
       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
           //Standard Java arrays are of a fixed length. After arrays are created,
           //they cannot grow or shrink, which means that you must know in advanced
           //how many elements an array will hold.

           //Array lists are vreated with an initial size. When this size is exceeded
           //the collection is automatically enlarged. When objects are removed,
           //the array may be shrunk.

           ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

           names.add("James");//0
           names.add("Peter");//1
           names.add("John");//2
           names.add("Jake");//3
           names.add("Paul");//4

           for (int i = 0 ; i < names.size(); i++)
           {
               System.out.println(names.get(i));
           }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList` refers to your class itself, as you have named it `ArrayList`. Either rename it<sub>[(Demo)](https://ideone.com/iyVowR)</sub> (note that you will need to change the class declaration as well as the file name unless you are using an IDE that can handle the renaming for you) or remove the import and qualify all access to `java.util.ArrayList`<sub>[(Demo)](https://ideone.com/6tziST)</sub> like so:

```
java.util.ArrayList<String> names = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Upvoting because maybe OP wants to keep the class name

Comment: @aran OP *shouldn't*. Giving your classes the same names as well-known classes is simply confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you have named your class `ArrayList`, so when you instantiate `names` the compiler isn't sure whether you want to create a new java ArrayList, or if you're referring to your own class.  Try renaming your class to something else, like "ArrayListTest".